# Sink Tap Aerator and Spout

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

Does the sink tap in the picture below have a threaded spout and a removable aerator ? How can this be determined ? I am planning to attach a benchtop dishwasher to this which will be only possible if the spout is threaded and the aerator removable. Shall be buying tools and attachments soon.

My guess is it does; the aerator has flats along each side, but I'd like to confirm since I am renting and do not wish to damage anything.

[image]

Comment: How nice it is to have one with flats.  Most do not and you have to hope to not damage the finish when using pliers to turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does. You should be able to just remove the bottom piece and the aerator is inside.

[image]

If you do need to use a wrench use smaller channel-locs and use a cloth to protect the finish from the teeth of the wrench.

[image]

Comment: I often am able to simply use a rubber glove, or a fat rubber band to remove the aerator by hand (otherwise it's just too small and slippery to get a good grip), with no risk of chewing it up with a tool.